# Integrating Chatbots from different platforms

Tags: artificial-intelligence, integration, chatbot, servicenow

I am working with different chatbot platforms: ServiceNow Virtual Agent, Avaya, and one of my own. So, I want to integrate all of these chatbots into one universal bot to avoid bot sprawling. How do I do it? Are there any specific tools that would help me with this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How would you decide to which bot the userQuestion would be sent? would you randomly switch between the bots or ask then all at the same time?

You could just write a simple frontend (googled this one on the fly: https://github.com/Jharrison23/ChatBot) and wire the REST APIs of the bots into it.

Comment: @GordonMohrin thanks for your response. That's where the AI part comes in. Identifying keywords, the AI will take care of. And what you're saying is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want multiple bots and another bot to judge where the question is sent. The universal bot should take care of any question. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: AI Bots are no joke and expensive to develop. What you want would take 3-5 developers 1/2 year and big data to train the chatbot. You can check out https://dialogflow.com/ or https://www.luis.ai/

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @GordonMohrin thanks for the links. They were really helpful.